# select not working with ng-repeat in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i am using ionic-framework, i am trying to bring dropdown select from list of items, but it does not work. it comes as words next to each other but not as dropdown or selectable dropdown

**HTML**

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
<select ng-model="food.customise">
  <option ng-repeat="cus in food.customise">{{cus}}</option>
</select>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that food.customise is an object. You can use ng-options instead of ng-repeat. And use a different model name.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="update(selectedItem)"  ng-init="selectedItem='Selec item'">
  <option ng-repeat="cus in food.customise">{{cus}}</option>
</select>
</label>
```

Controller code:

```
  $scope.update = function(selectedItem) {
      $scope.selectedItemValue = selectedItem;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
<select ng-model="food.customise" ng-options="cus in food.customise"></select>
</label>
```